# How to resize a svg icon (use href)

Tags: svg

I have all my icons added as symbols in the html file, eg:

```
<symbol id="flag-bg"><g fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-width="1pt"><path fill="#d62612" d="M0 319.997h640V480H0z"/><path fill="#fff" d="M0 0h640v160.003H0z"/><path fill="#00966e" d="M0 160.003h640v160.003H0z"/></g></symbol>
```

And I want to use it to display an icon of 32 by 24

```
<svg width="32" height="24" viewbox="0 0 32 24" id="#lg-bg"><use href="#flag-bg"><title></title></use></svg>
```

But it doesn't resize the flag to fill the size. What's the magic properties to make it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set a `viewBox` attribute on the `<symbol>` element that matches the size of its grafical content. To find out what size that is, you can use the `.getBBox()` function. Temporarily exchange `<symbol>` for `<svg>`, and don't mind if the grafical output makes no sense. You only need the numbers on the console:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('#flag-bg').getBBox())
```

```html
<svg>
  <svg id="flag-bg">
    <g fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-width="1pt">
      <path fill="#d62612" d="M0 319.997h640V480H0z"/>
      <path fill="#fff" d="M0 0h640v160.003H0z"/>
      <path fill="#00966e" d="M0 160.003h640v160.003H0z"/>
    </g>
  </svg>
</svg>
```

Then, use these values for your `viewBox`. There is no need to set a size on the `<use>` element, it defaults to 100% (of the surrounding `<svg>`) element.

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <symbol id="flag-bg" viewbox="0 0 640 480">
    <g fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-width="1pt">
      <path fill="#d62612" d="M0 319.997h640V480H0z"/>
      <path fill="#fff" d="M0 0h640v160.003H0z"/>
      <path fill="#00966e" d="M0 160.003h640v160.003H0z"/>
    </g>
  </symbol>
</svg>

<svg width="32" height="24" viewbox="0 0 32 24" id="#lg-bg">
  <use href="#flag-bg"><title></title></use>
</svg>
```

Comment: Cool, that was the missing part: add the viewbox on the symbol. i've added the d3 line I used to adjust all the flags. thanks!

Comment: I just erroneously rejected your edit (which would have been better left as a comment), and now I can't see it any more - besides fixing the `<svg>/<symbol>` exchange, what was your second point again?

Comment: Ah, found it again: " You can automatically adjust the symbols and add the missing viewbox, eg with d3: `d3.selectAll("#flags symbol").attr("viewBox","0 0 640 420")`"

Answer (score 0):

you can use viewbox property to scale your svg icon 
   check this code and reference link in below

```
<h1>Auto-Scaling an SVG Image with a <code>viewBox</code>
<div>&mdash;watch out for IE and table layouts</div></h1>
<figure>
<figcaption><code>img</code>, 100xauto height</figcaption>
<div>
<img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/91525/potofgold.svg" 
style="width:100px">
</div>
</figure>
<figure>
<figcaption><code>img</code>, auto widthx50</figcaption>
<div>
<img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/91525/potofgold.svg" 
 style="height:50px">
</div>
</figure>
<figure>
<figcaption><code>img</code>, auto size</figcaption>
<div>
<img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/91525/potofgold.svg">
</div>
</figure>
```

you can use viewbox property and scale your svg icons in it ..

reference link [clickhere](https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/)

Comment: also you may use this link [link] https://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-svg


to just convert your svg if you dont want to go through coding ... select height and width during your file upload and it will do the job for you

Comment: Hi, I should have clarified: I need to keep the svg inline for other purpose, so img is simplier indeed, but can't help in my case. thanks!

Comment: its ok ,  i will do it for you if you allow me , i will make example how to do this by giving class to the Svg , you may change heigh and width in the class and it would reflect directly to the SVG icon  tag in html ... would that be ok for u ?

Comment: or you also may give me link to your svg page and from there i will do it for you  .. its up to you ... good luck whatever you are dong

Comment: oh never mind , i see that you got it already ... have a good day